# Angular 2+ and service in service

Tags: angular

I want to use one service in another. I want to call getPrivateLessons from private-lessons.service in parametrs-results.service, but it not working, it returns me "undefined". Also, I have provide both services in modules. How to fix it?

private-lessons.service

```
@Injectable()
export class PrivateLessonsService {

  private _privateLessonsUrl: string = "http://localhost:3000/api/lessons";

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  getPrivateLessons() {
    return this._http.get(this._privateLessonsUrl)
      .map( (response: Response) => response.json() );    
  }
}
```

parametrs-results.service

```
@Injectable()
export class ParametrsResultsService {

  privateLessons: PrivateLesson[];

  constructor(private _privateLessonsService: PrivateLessonsService) { 
    this._privateLessonsService
      .getPrivateLessons()
      .subscribe(responseData => this.privateLessons = responseData);
  }


  getPrivateLessons() {
    return this.privateLessons;
  }

}
```

edit:

When i use

```
 this._privateLessonsService
  .getPrivateLessons()
  .subscribe(responseData => {

  this.privateLessons = responseData;
  console.log('this.privateLessons', this.privateLessons);

});
```

...it shows privateLessons properly. When i want to use getPrivateLessons in component i get 'undefined'. I need that data for the further operations in my service. How to fix it?

Comment: what is undefined the service itself or the privateLesson array ?

Comment: this.privateLessons in parametrs-resultsService, when calling getPrivateLessons().

Comment: I am not sure why you try to reroute through another service and not just use the first service but if you need to do it, try to change the `getPrivateLessons` method to make call the other service, instead of using the constructor for it. (which also removes the `privateLessons` property)

Comment: I need to store data in privateLesson variable in this service for the next operations.

Answer (score 0):

Like I worte in my comment above, I am not sure what is your motivation to reroute the call trough another service but if you need to do so, try this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ParametrsResultsService {

    constructor(private _privateLessonsService: PrivateLessonsService) { 
    }


    getPrivateLessons() {
        return this._privateLessonsService
        .getPrivateLessons();
    }

}
```

Comment: I need to store data in privateLesson variable in this service for the next operations.